# Iterate over two list of different sizes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

```
Value = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
content = ['a','b','c','d']

for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(Value , content):
   print(a,b)
```

The Output that i get using the above code is as follows:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 None
6 None
```

what I am Looking for is :

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 a
6 b
```

basically once one list is exhausted it should take the values again from starting. if any one could help would mean alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` with `zip` instead:

```
import itertools
Value = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
content = ['a','b','c','d']

for a,b in zip(Value , itertools.cycle(content)):
   print(a,b)
```

This outputs:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 a
6 b
```